Postgresql LISTEN NOTIFY dynamic channel vs dynamic payload
Which LISTEN/NOTIFY implementation is more performing and resource efficient? Please explain why.
With dynamic channel
// Send message to user with ID = 1 with content hello
NOTIFY message_1, 'hello';

user with listen using a unique channel. Unique per user
LISTEN message_1

or
Dynamic Payload
// Send message to user with ID = 1 with content hello
NOTIFY message, 'id=1;content=hello';

every user with listen using the same channel and get the content based on their id
LISTEN message

I've tried to implement websocket notification using pg_notify, i've tried to use dynamic channel but kinda curious about the performance if i just combined all of them into one single channel.

You've failed to give any information as to how many users, how many notifications, what hardware etc. This is unanswerable.

@RichardHuxton  you can answer with your own assumption, no need to cry

Using a dynamic payload with a single channel is generally more efficient than using unique channels per user. With dynamic payload What you can do is you can send messages to single channel and let users filter out what is relevant to them which is based on the payload content. This simplifies the implementation and also reduces the overhead of managing multiple channels.
